# i could not run my django project which has been cloned from git why

Tags: python, django

## Exception in thread django-main-thread:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application `enter code here`'vivawalleetintegration.wsgi' could not be loaded; Error importing module#
```

Comment: Share you command and folder structure.

Comment: Your error message says "Error importing module". When you clone a project, you dont automatically install necessary packages. If this project you're talking about uses a library that you haven't installed yet, then its pretty normal to see this kind of error. I'd recommend you to check script's first lines where the imports are listed, if there is a library with missing installment, it should be underlined in your code editor. Then just install that and move on

Answer (score 0):

if there is no requirements file or similar in the clogged repository, then you need to independently figure out which dependencies and libraries are installed and install them in your local environment.